# How to remove Contact Print Theme Editor, Contact Print Editor, Kmail Header Theme Editor etc?

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04, kde

In Kubuntu 18.04 I have a lot of applications that I never use and don't care for. Not only Kmail and Kontact that I can remove, but also Contact Print Theme Editor, Contact Print Editor, even Kmail Header Theme Editor, which I cannot find with Synaptic, not even with Discover.

They appear as `contactprintthemeeditor`, `contactprinteditor` and `headerthemeeditor` in System Activity list, but cannot be removed with apt under those names.

Are they part of a larger package?

How to remove them? They appear in my search/launcher and I find that confusing as I never use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .desktop files corresponding to `contactprintthemeeditor`, `contactthemeeditor` (not `contactprinteditor` which isn't on my system) and `headerthemeeditor` are:

- /usr/share/applications/org.kde.contactprintthemeeditor.desktop
- /usr/share/applications/org.kde.contactthemeeditor.desktop
- /usr/share/applications/org.kde.headerthemeeditor.desktop

Copy these .desktop files over to `~/.local/share/applications` and edit them to add a line containing `NoDisplay=true`. That will prevent these items from appearing in your menus. The same approach maybe used to hide anything else you don't want to see.

Modifying the version in `~/.local/share/applications` will ensure the change you make survives a software update.

As to the origins of these items,

```
locate contactprintthemeeditor contactthemeeditor headerthemeeditor | grep -E "\/usr\/bin"
```

gives me

```
/usr/bin/contactprintthemeeditor
/usr/bin/contactthemeeditor
/usr/bin/headerthemeeditor
```

Running `dpkg -S` for each of them gives

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/contactprintthemeeditor
kdepim-themeeditors: /usr/bin/contactprintthemeeditor
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/contactthemeeditor
kdepim-themeeditors: /usr/bin/contactthemeeditor
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/headerthemeeditor
kdepim-themeeditors: /usr/bin/headerthemeeditor
$
```

And one can get more information on KDE PIM [here](https://community.kde.org/KDE_PIM). From there:

> KDE PIM is part of KDE. Its goal is to provide a suite of applications to manage personal information. This includes mail, calendar, contacts and more. The main result is **Kontact**, our personal information manager.

Looking at a partial output of `apt depends kontact` shows entries relating to `kdepim` and to `grantlee` ([which provides the theme aspects](https://github.com/KDE/grantlee-editor/blob/master/contactprintthemeeditor/contactprintthemeeditor.qrc)):

```
$ apt depends kontact 
kontact
  Depends: kdepim-runtime
  Depends: kio
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0)
  Depends: libkf5completion5 (>= 4.97.0)
  Depends: libkf5configcore5 (>= 4.98.0)
  Depends: libkf5configgui5 (>= 4.97.0)
  Depends: libkf5configwidgets5 (>= 5.23.0)
  Depends: libkf5coreaddons5 (>= 5.2.0)
  Depends: libkf5crash5 (>= 5.15.0)
  Depends: libkf5grantleetheme-plugins
  Depends: libkf5grantleetheme5 (>= 16.08.0)
  Depends: libkf5i18n5 (>= 4.97.0)
  Depends: libkf5iconthemes5 (>= 4.96.0)
  Depends: libkf5kcmutils5 (>= 5.0.0)
  Depends: libkf5kdepimdbusinterfaces5 (>= 4:15.12)
  Depends: libkf5kiowidgets5 (>= 4.96.0)
  Depends: libkf5kontactinterface5 (>= 15.08.0)
  Depends: libkf5libkdepim-plugins
  Depends: libkf5libkdepim5abi2 (>= 4:17.
  .
  .
  .
```

So it's probable that purging `kontact` from your system will directly rid you of the various items you've mentioned and certainly clean up your menu!

If not, try:

```
sudo apt remove kdepim-themeeditors
```

By the way, at this time, [KDE Neon's manifest](https://files.kde.org/neon/images/neon-useredition/current/neon-useredition-20180621-1024-amd64.manifest) *doesn't* include `kontact`.

Comment: removing `kontact` has removed some other packages but not the ones mentioned.

Comment: what needed to be removed was `kdepim-themeeditors`, as indicated by the command you posted:  `dpkg -S`. Solved.