# How to remove KDE PIM modules from Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma-5

I would like to remove all KDE PIM related modules: kmail, calendar, akonadi and the db etc as I am not using them actively. There is no clear documentation on how to uninstall those modules apart from some old discussion board comments which are caught between KDE/plasma 4 and 5.

So how do I safely uninstall PIM modules on ubuntu 18.04 which is plasma 5.12? I was using them and I can see these processes running, if there is a way to completely disable them, that can work too.

Comment: If you've backed up your personal data, the easiest way would be to do a clean install of Kubuntu 18.04 making sure you choose the **minimal** install option. Otherwise, you can certainly get rid of most all the stuff you've listed. I'd take it one thing at a time using the terminal and `apt -s purge` as a simulation so that you can see the effect of what you propose to remove. To know what to remove, look at the `Exec=` lines in various `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications` for package names. Purge just one at a time. All the best!

Comment: Related:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048762/how-to-remove-contact-print-theme-editor-contact-print-editor-kmail-header-the

Comment: Can you also please explain "I was using them and I can see these processes running,"? Were you using them in the current session, or some days ago and not since then?

Comment: I used to use them: kmail, korganizer etc, or I tried using them, until I realised that they do not suffice my need. I still see the apps/services like mysql, akonadi start on boot, even if I disable kmail, kontact from launching automatically. I would just like to uninstall these PIM apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bionic Beaver (18.04), a minimal install option is offered to users. Ubuntu, Ubuntu Mate, and Kubuntu are three distributions I know of that offer the option.

For Kubuntu 18.04, you'll see this (taken from [here](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/73271-Provide-Kubuntu-Minimal-installer-with-pure-KDE-like-in-Ubuntu-18-04?p=412340&viewfull=1#post412340)):

[image: Kubuntu Minimal]

The [release notes for Kubuntu 18.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu) have this:

> **Minimal install option**
>   This is now available in the installer for Kubuntu.
>
> For Kubuntu this **removes KDE PIM applications**, Libreoffice, Cantata and mpd, plus some additional internet and media applications. At present a full Plasma Desktop is left in place, plus basic applications and utilities. Firefox as a browser, and VLC as a media player, are also retained.

A list of what is **not** included in the minimal install relative to the full install is [here](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/kubuntu.bionic/desktop.minimal-remove). I can't say how up to date the list is but there's a section on `KDE PIM` to provide you guidance in case you want to remove stuff from an **existing full install**.

```
# KDE PIM

accountwizard
akonadi-backend-mysql
akonadi-server
akregator
kaddressbook
kdepim-addons
kdepim-runtime
kdepim-themeeditors
kleopatra
kmail
knotes
kontact
korganizer
ktnef
mbox-importer
pim-data-exporter
pim-sieve-editor
```

I've checked some of the entries above using `apt purge -s package-name`. Each of the packages I checked only removed the named package and nothing else.

There's also a section titled `residual deps/reverse-deps`.

```
# residual deps/reverse-deps

ktorrent-data
konversation-data
mysql-client-core-5.7
mysql-server-core-5.7
kde-config-mailtransport
kf5-kdepim-apps-libs-data
kf5-messagelib-data
kio-ldap
kio-sieve
libkf5akonadiagentbase5
libkf5akonadicalendar5abi2
libkf5akonadicalendar-data
libkf5akonadicontact5abi1
libkf5akonadicontact-data
libkf5akonadicore5abi1
libkf5akonadicore-bin
libkf5akonadimime5
libkf5akonadimime-data
libkf5akonadinotes5
libkf5akonadinotes-data
libkf5akonadiprivate5
libkf5akonadisearch-bin
libkf5akonadisearchcore5
libkf5akonadisearch-data
libkf5akonadisearchdebug5
libkf5akonadisearchpim5
libkf5akonadisearch-plugins
libkf5akonadisearchxapian5
libkf5akonadiwidgets5
libkf5alarmcalendar5abi1
libkf5alarmcalendar-data
libkf5calendarcore5abi1
libkf5calendarsupport5abi1
libkf5calendarsupport-data
libkf5calendarutils5abi1
libkf5calendarutils-bin
libkf5calendarutils-data
libkf5contacteditor5
libkf5contacteditor-data
libkf5contacts5
libkf5contacts-data
libkf5eventviews5
libkf5eventviews-data
libkf5followupreminder5
libkf5grantleetheme5
libkf5grantleetheme-data
libkf5grantleetheme-plugins
libkf5gravatar5
libkf5gravatar-data
libkf5identitymanagement5abi1
libkf5identitymanagement-data
libkf5imap5
libkf5imap-data
libkf5incidenceeditor5abi2
libkf5incidenceeditor-bin
libkf5incidenceeditor-data
libkf5kaddressbookgrantlee5
libkf5kaddressbookimportexport5
libkf5kdepimdbusinterfaces5
libkf5kmanagesieve5
libkf5kontactinterface5
libkf5kontactinterface-data
libkf5ksieve5
libkf5ksieve-data
libkf5ksieveui5
libkf5ldap5
libkf5ldap-data
libkf5libkdepim5abi2
libkf5libkdepimakonadi5
libkf5libkdepim-data
libkf5libkdepim-plugins
libkf5libkleo5abi1
libkf5mailcommon5abi4
libkf5mailcommon-plugins
libkf5mailimporter5abi1
libkf5mailimporterakonadi5
libkf5mailimporter-data
libkf5mailtransport5abi2
libkf5mailtransportakonadi5
libkf5mailtransport-data
libkf5mbox5
libkf5messagecomposer5abi2
libkf5messagecore5abi2
libkf5messagelist5abi1
libkf5messageviewer5abi4
libkf5messageviewer-plugins
libkf5mime5abi2
libkf5mime-data
libkf5mimetreeparser5abi2
libkf5pimcommon5abi3
libkf5pimcommonakonadi5
libkf5pimcommon-plugins
libkf5pimtextedit5abi2
libkf5pimtextedit-data
libkf5sendlater5
libkf5syndication5
libkf5templateparser5abi2
libkf5tnef5
libkf5tnef-data
libkf5webengineviewer5abi3
libkpimgapicalendar5
libkpimgapicontacts5
libkpimgapitasks5
libkpimimportwizard5
libkpimkdav5
libkpimkdav-data
```

It's also useful to run `akonadictl status` to what see `akonadi`is up to on your system. On my system, I see:

```
$ akonadictl status
Akonadi Control: stopped
Akonadi Server: stopped
Akonadi Server Search Support: available (Remote Search)
Available Agent Types: akonadi_akonotes_resource, akonadi_archivemail_agent, akonadi_birthdays_resource, akonadi_contacts_resource, akonadi_davgroupware_resource, akonadi_ews_resource, akonadi_ewsmta_resource, akonadi_facebook_resource, akonadi_followupreminder_agent, akonadi_googlecalendar_resource, akonadi_googlecontacts_resource, akonadi_ical_resource, akonadi_icaldir_resource, akonadi_imap_resource, akonadi_indexing_agent, akonadi_invitations_agent, akonadi_kalarm_dir_resource, akonadi_kalarm_resource, akonadi_kolab_resource, akonadi_maildir_resource, akonadi_maildispatcher_agent, akonadi_mailfilter_agent, akonadi_mbox_resource, akonadi_migration_agent, akonadi_mixedmaildir_resource, akonadi_newmailnotifier_agent, akonadi_notes_agent, akonadi_notes_resource, akonadi_openxchange_resource, akonadi_pop3_resource, akonadi_sendlater_agent, akonadi_tomboynotes_resource, akonadi_vcard_resource, akonadi_vcarddir_resource
$
```

And `man akonadictl` has

```
stop   : Stops the Akonadi server and all its processes cleanly
```

which you may find useful.

Another useful command is `compgen`:

```
$ compgen -c | grep mysql
mysqld
mysqld-akonadi
mysql
mysql_upgrade
mysql_install_db
mysql_embedded
mysqlcheck
$
```

On my system, both `pgrep -i -al akonadi` and `pgrep -i -al mysql` come up empty.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am not looking for a complete re-install. I just need to get rid of the applications I do not use. Besides, I need and use libreoffice and cantata.. I do not think minimal is an option for me right now.

Comment: Awesome.. `akonadictl stop` is superb idea.. akonadi restarts when kmail/korganizer starts. but I guess, I can make sure somehow they dont start and this can work! need to find a way to run this at startup and kill korganizer daemon.

Comment: I think you maybe able to find out about `korganizer` by running `pgrep -i -al korganizer` and then using the proper term to make a small script to kill it using `pkill process-name`. You can then use Kubuntu's GUI in `System Settings` > `Startup and Shutdown` > `Autostart` to add that and other scripts of your choice.

Comment: I have added this to my Autostart, it stops the akonadi services, and kills the korganizer service which doesnt stop with it. This is already recovering about 450+ mb RAM for me. Thanks @DK Bose
```
#! /bin/bash
sleep 10;
akonadictl stop;
pkill -9 korgac;
```